# Calling a Postgre SQL dump via ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a SQL dump which I want to be executed via ActiveRecord. I'm trying this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(File.read(sql_seeds))
```

But I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 18: 1 Shanghai 2012-12-20 10:31:31.350111 2012-12-20 10:31:31.35...
```

At this line of the SQL script:

```
COPY locations (id, description, created_at, updated_at) FROM stdin;
1       Shanghai        2012-12-20 10:31:31.350111      2012-12-20 10:31:31.350111
```

Some indications:

- `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("\\i #{sql_seeds}")` does not work because `\i` is a `psql` command (thank you @JiříPospíšil and @RichardHuxton)
- I don't want to `%X( psql -U #{user} -H #{host} -P #{pass} ... )`, because I would use the already existing ActiveRecord database connection.
- I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2 .

Comment: where is the documentation for \i queries? i did not find any.

Comment: It is a postgres command, you can find it here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/backup-dump.html
You can use it in sql scripts, for example in 1.sql you write `\i 2.sql`, and the contents of 2.sql will  be executed

Comment: sorry, but where exactly?

Comment: That's a psql command, not SQL. You'll need to pipe your script through psql not through a standard db connection.

Comment: Create a migration and execute the sql commands in it

Comment: @phoet : just search for `\i` in the documentation
@RichardHuxton : you are right; I am trying to understand why reading the file and executing it does not work
@Anand : the execution inside a migration would not change anything; the question is the modality of execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `COPY FROM stdin`; redumping with `pg_dump --inserts` solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\i` is a `psql`'s command, not `postgresql`'s. You can't use it directly in queries. Also I don't see a reason why the `execute` method would fail while the import would work.

I think you will have to shell out, even if that means creating another db connection. Note that you don't need to assemble the `psql` command directly, you can use the `db` command:

```
rails db < seeds.sql
```

This way you can reuse the connection info in `config/database.yml` for the current environment.